# CSS Menu item disappears on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a menu implemented using CSS as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/vZgTP/.

When I hover on child items (Product I) most of the times it does not get highlighted as shown in figure – instead the child items get disappeared. How to resolve it? The CSS code is available in jsFiddle. It will be good if you can specify what change need to be done to resolve this.

Expected Behavior for children

[image: Expected Behavior for children]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I got it, check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZgTP/26/)

```
/*added padding-bottom: 8px;*/
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a{ background:#FF5500; border-color:#FF5500;  top:-1px; z-     index:999;  padding-bottom: 7px;}
```

Comment: well, the reason it was disappearing was because the second ul was set to appear a bit too low, so when the mouse left the tag that triggered it to appear, would fall in this a-few-pixel-tiny zone which acted like a boundary between it and the actual second ul (which had the Product1 and Product 2 li -s) making it to disappear since the pointer was out of both the trigger tag and the 2nd ul

Comment: Sorry don't have IE7 at the moment, but in IE8 it looks the same as in Chrome. I also couldn't find the compatibility-view mode under IE8 which would have rendered the page as in IE7, but I think I might have made it active some other day before. However, don't worry if it's just a small alignment problem under IE7 as many people are switching to newer versions of it. On top of that, if they use IE, they deserve it!

Comment: @menislici There is a slight alignment problem even in Chrome. The children's div's overlaps on tops of second menu item (i.e, Monitoring). How can we overcome this?

Comment: @EitanT you couldn't resist saying it in that way, could you? Nevertheless, I updated my answer.

Comment: I sorted that out by adding `padding-bottom: 7px;` to `#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a`. Funnily enough I had to remove what I previously added to make this work!

Answer (score 1):

Th problem is that the height of `<li class="has-sub">` is less then the height of the `<ul>`, so when you move the mouse down over the `<li>` it will stop hovering the `<li>` and start hovering the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a proper solution yet, but I think I found the reason. When you slowly move the mouse down to the sub-menu, there are a few pixels were the cursor does not hover over the #cssmenu > li anymore. This of course results in a disappearing sub-menu. If instead you move the mouse quickly, then the browser fires the mouse-event in the sub-menu.

A solution should be a seamless (or gap-less) transition from the #cssmenu > li to the sub-menu.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do the  seamless (or gap-less) transition from the #cssmenu > li to the sub-menu ?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the more difficult part, that I didn't have any time for left. But seems like @menislici just did it.